# Marketo REST API - increment field

Tags: marketo

If i have a custom object with an integer field, is there a way to send a request to increment this field by 1?
Or would i have to get that field's value, increment it and send it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot increment such a value with a single API call, so you either have to

- keep track of your records outside of Marketo too, and update Marketo with the current value;
- or you have to use two API calls: one to fetch the record, and a second one to send back the updated value.

**Note**:
While it is possible to increment/decrement the `Score` [field type](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/fields/field-types/) (which is also an integer field) with integer values, it is only possible to do so through the [`Change Score`](https://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Change+Score) flow step within Marketo. Besides that, the `Score` type is not available for custom objects.

To be sure, I just have tried to increment an integer value via the API by setting “+1” as a sent value, but it was recorded as plain “1”, so the original record has been overwritten.